# Preferred method for programmatically disabling wifi on android

Tags: android

Hi I'm new to android and was wondering what the preferred method of disabling wifi in my app. Both methods work fine but which is preferred/faster.

1

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
```

Uses the following permission.

```
CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
```

2

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
    }
```

Uses the following permission.

```
CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the following permissions in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Then you can use the following in your activity class:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
```

You can, but its not really necessary, to use the following to check if it's enabled or not

```
boolean wifiEnabled = wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()
```